# Using Linux Environment Variables in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, PHP 5.2, VMWare (with Ubuntu Server V11.04)

My plan is to create an environment variable in both the linux and windows platforms, and to make them work in PHP. So I created the variable "ROOT_DIR" in Windows and another "ROOT_DIR" variable in Windows.

I have this code in PHP that I expect to work in both the platforms:

```
<?php
echo 'My username is ' .$_ENV["ROOT_DIR"] . '!';
?>
```

But in Linux, all it outputs is NULL. I wonder what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `getenv()`?

Comment: Surely it outputs "My username is" and "!", right?

Comment: I suspect this not PHP, but Linux/bash question. How did you define the variable? Did you use "export"?

Comment: I have tried getenv and it also didn't work. Yes I have used "export".

Comment: How do you run the code? Is it CLI or web script?

Comment: I try it in the web browser.

Comment: Duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941136/php-and-apache-environment-variables

Comment: The answer in that question also didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after editing config?

Comment: yes I did. I'll try the answer below, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script through the browser then try adding the following to your  main `.htaccess` file

```
SetEnv ROOT_DIR "/path/to/root/"
```

[apache setenv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html)

Comment: seems like I don't have a .htaccess file inside the /var/www folder. Can I just create one?

Comment: This worked. But I had to use _SERVER instead of _ENV. Or maybe I could edit my windows' htaccess so i can use _SERVER in windows as well. Where is the htaccess in Windows?

Comment: You can create a new one and place it in your root directory.

Comment: i did but it didn't work. Is there any file I should edit so that .htaccess would work?

Comment: Try adding an invalid command/text/code to the .htaccess and see if the server will be affected (by responding with with code 500). This is a way to tell that the .htaccess is actually read by the server